# Unable to access contents of IFRAME in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm having difficulty encountering the `contents()` of an IFRAME via jQuery.  It is actually a frame within a frame that I'm trying to access.  The frames are all from the same source (same domain, same root path, etc.).

I'm currently accessing the frame via:

```
var $frame = $(window.top.frames[1].document).find('#innerFrameName');
```

This works fine, and if I `console.log` the value of $frame, I see that it's a jQuery array:

```
[<frame src=​"mypage.htm" id=​"innerFrameName" frameborder=​"1" border=​"1" scrolling=​"auto" title=​"My Inner Frame" name=​"bsscright">​]
```

However, the moment I try to call the following (as explained in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1639342/107277)), I get an empty array.

```
var $contents = $frame.contents();
console.log($contents);       // => []
```

Even if I try to get to the document itself, I can't.

```
var innerDocument = $frame.get(0).document;
console.log(innerDocument);   // => undefined
```

I even tried going about it without jQuery, and I'm getting the same results as above.

```
var innerFrame = window.top.frames[1].frames['innerFrameName'];
var innerDocument = innerFrame.document;
console.log(innerFrame);     // => the DOM object representing the IFRAME
console.log(innerDocument);  // => undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Using frames? :)

Comment: Trust me, it's not by choice! It's a third-party product.

Answer (score -1):

This is untested, you are supposed to use contents when accessing the frame. I would assume it would be:

```
var someDivs = $("#outerIframe").contents().find("#innerIframe").contents().find("div");
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.  The first call to `contents()` returns an empty array.

Comment: and you are calling this after both iframes are loaded?

Comment: I've got the call happening withing the jQuery ready event.  I also tried moving these to be the last scripts being called just to make sure every other script has loaded before this one.